# Little CLI game in C++ with random words

Tags: c++, game, console, hangman

the game is quite simple, you have to constantly guess the letters of a hidden word, but has a limited number of wrong attempts. The word you are looking for should be a random word from Wikipedia. I would like to get a review from you.

I used libcURL and the [cURLpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp) wrapper.

Compilation (with Cygwin): `g++ -L/usr/local/lib Hangman.cpp -o hm.exe -lcurl -lcurlpp`

`Hangman.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

using namespace std;

string getRandomWordFromWikipedia()
{
    curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;
    curlpp::Easy handle;
    handle.setOpt(curlpp::options::Url(string("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/special:random")));
    handle.setOpt(curlpp::options::FollowLocation(true));
    ostringstream os;
    os << handle;
    string seq = os.str();
    regex rgx1("<h1.+id=\"firstHeading\"[^>]*>(.+)</h1>");
    regex rgx2("<[^>]+>(.+)</[^>]+>");
    smatch sm1;
    if (regex_search(seq, sm1, rgx1))
    {
        string seq2 = sm1[1];
        while (seq2.find("<") != string::npos)
        {
            smatch sm2;
            if (regex_search(seq2, sm2, rgx2))
            {
                seq2 = sm2[1];
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return seq2;
    }
    return "";
}

struct ToFind
{
    string w1;
    string w2;
    int tries = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int health = 100;
    int hintsLeft = 2;
};

void initToFind(struct ToFind *stf)
{
    string w1 = getRandomWordFromWikipedia();
    string w2;
    for (int i = 0; i < w1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (w1[i] == ' ')
        {
            w2 += "  ";
        }
        else
        {
            w2 += "_ ";
        }
    }
    stf->w1 = w1;
    stf->w2 = w2;
}

int findInToFind(struct ToFind *stf, char c)
{
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stf->w1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (stf->w1[i] == c && stf->w2[i * 2] == '_')
        {
            f++;
            stf->right++;
            stf->w2[i * 2] = c;
        }
    }
    stf->tries++;
    if (f > 0)
    {
        stf->right++;
    }
    else
    {
        stf->health -= 10;
    }
    return f;
}

void printStatistics(struct ToFind *stf)
{
    static int round = 1;
    cout << "Round:      " << round << endl;
    cout << "Tries:      " << stf->tries << endl;
    cout << "Rights:     " << stf->right << endl;
    cout << "Health:     " << stf->health << " from 100" << endl;
    cout << "Hints left: " << stf->hintsLeft << endl;
    round++;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct ToFind stf;
    initToFind(&stf);
    if (stf.w1.empty())
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "The game begins!" << endl;
    cout << "The word you are looking for has a length of " << stf.w1.size() << endl;
    while (stf.w2.find("_") != string::npos && stf.health > 0)
    {
        printStatistics(&stf);
        cout << stf.w2 << endl;
        cout << "Which letter next?" << endl;
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        int f = findInToFind(&stf, c);
        if (f > 0)
        {
            cout << "Great, the letter " << c << " appeared " << f << " times!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unfortunately you weren't lucky this time ..." << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "The game is over ..." << endl;
    if (stf.health > 0)
    {
        cout << "Great, you found the word " << stf.w1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unfortunately you didn't find the word " << stf.w1 << " and you're dead." << endl;
    }
    printStatistics(&stf);
    cout << "Any char to continue ..." << endl;
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I see in retrospect a logical error in `findInToFind`. `right` is incremented multiple times. It should be incremented only once and should indicate the percentage of correct attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## General Observations

An interesting new twist on an old game! Using Wikipedia as a source gives a lot of possible words.

There is a lot of good ideas here, but there can be some improvement. An example of possible improvements is to make the `struct ToFind` data structure more object oriented. More on this later.

The code already follows some good best practices such as always using braces (`{` and `}`) around code blocks.

Using raw pointers (`struct ToFind* stf`) is generally considered a bad practice in C++, there are better ways to do what the code is doing. The use of the raw pointer makes this code look more like `C` rather than `C++`.

For performance reasons, it is better to end output lines with `"\n"` rather than using `std::endl`. `std::endl` flushes the output buffer which generally isn't necessary and could be a system call. Using `"\n"` rather than `std::endl` also seems to simplify the code a little bit:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    struct ToFind stf;
    initToFind(&stf);
    if (!stf.hasWord())
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "The game begins!\n";
    std::cout << "The word you are looking for has a length of " << stf.w1.size() << "\n";
    while (stf.w2.find("_") != string::npos && stf.health > 0)
    {
        stf.printStatistics();
        std::cout << stf.w2 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Which letter next?\n";
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        int f = findInToFind(&stf, c);
        if (f > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Great, the letter " << c << " appeared " << f << " times!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unfortunately you weren't lucky this time ...\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The game is over ..." << "\n";
    if (stf.stillAlive())
    {
        std::cout << "Great, you found the word " << stf.w1 << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unfortunately you didn't find the word " << stf.w1 << " and you're dead. \n";
    }
    stf.printStatistics();
    std::cout << "Any char to continue ...\n";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note that `main()` is doing too much, it should be one or two more functions.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

## Object Oriented Code

The code could be simplified if the `struct ToFind` contained a constructor and some methods (member functions). Personally I would use a `class` rather than a `struct`, so that the member variables could be private, but to give you some idea look at the following code and also the modified example of `main()` above. *Please note that making this object oriented removes the need to pass a pointer around*.

```
struct ToFind
{
    std::string w1;
    std::string w2;
    int tries;
    int right;
    int health;
    int hintsLeft;

    ToFind()
        : tries(0), right(0), health(100), hintsLeft(2)
    {

    }

    ToFind(std::string word)
        : w1(word), tries(0), right(0), health(100), hintsLeft(2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < w1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (w1[i] == ' ')
            {
                w2 += "  ";
            }
            else
            {
                w2 += "_ ";
            }
        }
    }

    void setWord(std::string word1)
    {
        w1 = word1;
        for (int i = 0; i < w1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (w1[i] == ' ')
            {
                w2 += "  ";
            }
            else
            {
                w2 += "_ ";
            }
        }
    }

    void printStatistics()
    {
        static int round = 1;
        std::cout << "Round:      " << round << "\n";
        std::cout << "Tries:      " << tries << "\n";
        std::cout << "Rights:     " << right << "\n";
        std::cout << "Health:     " << health << " from 100" << "\n";
        std::cout << "Hints left: " << hintsLeft << "\n";
        round++;
    }

    bool hasWord()
    {
        return !w1.empty();
    }

    bool stillAlive()
    {
        return health > 0;
    }

    int findInToFind(char c)
    {
        int f = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < w1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (w1[i] == c && w2[i * 2] == '_')
            {
                f++;
                right++;
                w2[i * 2] = c;
            }
        }

        tries++;
        
        if (f > 0)
        {
            right++;
        }
        else
        {
            health -= 10;
        }

        return f;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks much more object-oriented than the original code.